# How to access multiple textbox by getElementsByName

Tags: javascript

I have written following code in html:

```
<input type="text" id="id_1" name="text_1">
<input type="text" id="id_2" name="text_2">
<input type="text" id="id_3" name="text_3">
```

Here I have to get all textBoxes in an array in javascript function whose id starts with "id". So, that I can get above two textBoxes in an array.

How to get all textBoxes whose id start with "id"?

Comment: you can simply define name and id as an array "text_1[]" so through this can you can access.. in java script just define $('#field_name').val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var matchingEle = [];
var eleName = '';

for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; ++i) {
 el = ele[i];
 eleName = el.getAttribute("name");
 if (eleName && eleName.indexOf("text_") == 0) {
     matchingEle.push(el);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var nodeList = document.querySelector("input[name^='text_'")
```

A nodeList should be sufficiently like an array for your purposes.

Note that [support for `querySelector`](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector) might not be sufficient for your purposes (in which you will need to `getElementsByTagName` and then filter the results in a loop).

Alternatively you could use a library which provides its own selector engine. In YUI 3 you could:

```
var listOfYUIObjects = Y.all("input[name^='text_'");
```

Mootools, Prototype, jQuery and a host of other libraries provide similar functionality.

Comment: I have changed my question please give me answer of edited question.

Comment: @rishikeshtadaka — Replace "name" and "text" with "id" in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');  //Array containing all the input controls
var textBoxArray = [];                              //target Array
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
{
    var node = list[i];

    if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'text' &&  node.getAttribute("id").substring(0, 1) == "id") 
    {
     /*
          insert matching textboxes into target array
     */
      textBoxArray.push(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic function that filters a list of elements based on a pattern. This is useful if you want to do a similar thing in future but with different criteria on the properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZKkh/

```
function filter(elements, pattern) {
    var i, j, match, e, f = [];

    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
        e = elements[i];
        match = true;

        for (j in pattern) {
            if (pattern.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                if (!(j in e && pattern[j](e[j]))) {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (match) {
            f.push(e);
        }
    }

    return f;
}

var pattern = {
    'type': function (t) {
        return t.toLowerCase() === 'text';
    },
    'name': function (t) {
        return t.toLowerCase().search('text') === 0;
    }
};

console.log(filter(document.getElementsByTagName("input"), pattern));
```